# Find the value of dropdown from each row in a table

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a table and each row has two dropdowns. I am trying to store the entire table values in an array using javascript.

I am able to fetch the values of cells[0] and cells[1] but not cells[3] and cells[4] which contain dropdowns.

Here is my javascript

```
    $(document).on('click', '#classTypeFetch', function (e) {
    var table = document.getElementById('tblClassificationSearchResult');
    var tableArray = [];
    for (var i = 1; i < table.rows.length; i++) {
        tableArray.push({
            charName: table.rows[i].cells[0].innerHTML,
            charDesc: table.rows[i].cells[1].innerHTML,
            parentValue: table.rows[i].cells[2].getElementById("ddlParent").value,
            childValue: table.rows[i].cells[3].getElementById("ddlParent").value,
        });
    }
    var result = tableArray;
});
```

Comment: You can't repeat ids man.  Ids must be unique for a document.  As such the lookup for 'ddlParent' is most likely bad.  Change those to classes and try that.

Comment: What is the error?  Does `getElementById` even work on an element like that?  What does it return?  If you have multiple elements with the same `id`, what do you expect it to return?

Comment: Optionally you could try changing it to `getElementsByTagName('select')[0].value`

Comment: Show your `table` HTML.... 2 or 3 rows...

Comment: Anyone know if there is a S.O. specifically addressing the unique id issue?  This comes up so often it seems that I'm starting to think i need to bookmark it for quick pasting into question comments...

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9454645/does-id-have-to-be-unique-in-the-whole-page  wham

Comment: adding indivudual ids to each element helped. Thankyou @Taplar

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Does ID have to be unique in the whole page?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9454645/does-id-have-to-be-unique-in-the-whole-page)